# Is there a way to accept apostrophes when inserting variables to MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having some trouble where I'm pulling values from both a session and a form - for a ticketing system - and when someone uses an apostrophe, it breaks the code.

See below where I receive the data:

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$topic = $_POST["topic"];
$urgency = $_POST["urgency"];
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
$details = $_POST["details"];
$username = $_SESSION["username"];
$imgloc = $_SESSION["imgloc"];
$isit = $_SESSION["isit"];
```

I later insert it into my MSQL database here:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tickets (id, ticketname, urgency, topic, submitted, subject, details, isticketimage, imgloc) VALUES ('', '$name', '$urgency', '$topic', '$userno', '$subject', '$details', '$isit', '$imgloc')";
```

How would I amend this code to avoid apostrophe's breaking my mysql command?

Comment: You should use Prepared Statements, that will sort it, and other issues.

Comment: Also, if your `id` column has a default, there's no need to include it in the query with a blank value, just omit it and it will use the default.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement)

Answer (score 1):

You can use PDO from php, it will avoid sql injections.

You can do something like this

```php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
$sql = "INSERT INTO tickets (ticketname, urgency, topic, submitted, subject, details, isticketimage, imgloc) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$name, $urgency, $topic, $userno, $subject, $details, $isit, $imgloc]);
```

More info : https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's good to see you wanting to contribute, but questions like these are asked on a daily basis and already have plenty of answers on the site, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Please do a search of the site before answering to avoid creating duplicate content and flag the question as duplicate instead.

Answer (score -2):

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConnection, $variable)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string` should be avoided because [it's not safe enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string). Prepared statements are the way to go.